# Objective-c load BIO from bundle

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, openssl

I would like to load a text file using `BIO_new_file(myPath, "r")` in objective-c.
As path I obtain the current document directory from the bundle.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/test.txt", documentsDirectory];

NSLog(@"%@", fileName);

const char* cString = [fileName cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

BIO *temp = BIO_new_file(cString, "r");
if (!temp) {
    NSLog(@"Could not load file!");
    assert(false);
}
```

But the method couldn't load the file and I receive the `Could not load file!`.

Is this a known issue when using Openssl's BIO in objective-c? Are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps there is no file named `test.txt` in your application's documents directory.  Try logging the error code:

```
NSLog(@"error code = %s (%d)", strerror(errno), errno);
```

Comment: Thanks. I was so sure that the file must be there but it was in the bundle root and not in the document directory. Such a dump failure cost me 2 hours... But that's software development... ;)